# Why does Data Loader force a record update (last modified) with only the record ID?

Tags: data-loader, data, loader

I have seen this and I cannot find documentation as to why just updating with the record ID would force a record update as seen in the "Last Modified  Date" field. It seem odd that "updating" the identification number of a record would trigger an record update.

Not explained in here either:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/inserting_updating_or_deleting_data.htm

Comment: what do you mean by "updating with the record id"?

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a handy way to 'touch' the SObjects identified by the CSV ID column.

As such, you can use it to mass execute before/after update triggers, and WFR/Process Builders that are defined to execute unconditionally.  These operations might be useful for doing some complex data migration that is otherwise too difficult to replicate with spreadsheet work or that you need to have certain side effects happen (like callouts or platform events)